# ISS DMA vs C&DH?

Tags: iss

The Early design of the ISS specified a global Data Management System (DMS) for operations and management of Station software-dependant systems. The DMS was based on ISO/OSI standards for communications and was a large scale distributed processing network based on commercial standards for networked computing systems.  The final design is the Command & Data Handling System (C&DH) which more closely resembles a traditional embedded command and control system.  When did this design transition occur?  I worked on the DMS design in the late 80's, early 90's and then left the program.  I am curious to know when the decision was made to follow a more traditional embedded command & control methodology.

Comment: Was it Space Station Freedom when you worked on it?

Comment: It was.  I still have a license plate holder on my car that says "Team Member - Space Station Freedom".

Comment: I figured. The change you're asking about probably came in when it turned into ISS, but I don't have details.

Comment: Another naming attempt that never gained traction was "Space Station Alpha".

Comment: There was a big fight over that between the crew and management.